# How to view the jetty version used in gradle jetty plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle, jetty, version

In my `build.gradle` I enabled Jetty plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'
```

How to I see the actual jetty version is used in this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradle jetty plugin seems to be using

```
'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.25'
```

atleast since 2012. [Source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/95032b647892dce5593e70e3202edc1b2d0bd31e/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L68).

If you're looking for newer gradle launched jetty, you should look into [Gretty](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty).

---

Alternatively, you can get version information from jetty process through JMX. You need to start jetty with jmx enabled. To do this, add this config to your build.gradle:

```
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.with {
    jettyConfig= file('src/main/resources/jetty-config.xml')
    additionalRuntimeJars =  sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

you will also need:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-management:6.1.25'
}
```

The contents of `jetty-config.xml` [are here](https://gist.github.com/foragerr/da7e89e8dbf7b2562b77). You can now start jetty with either `gradle jettyrun` or `gradle jettyrunwar` and attach any jmx reader, like jconsole to the running java process. Expand the JMX Tree:

[image]

Which gives you, Tada!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. And if there is any way other way looking source will be great

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking as well, as a way of confirmation. Since jetty doesn't have a management console like tomcat, I was looking for other ways to get jetty version from the process after starting jetty from gradle. Apparently jetty exposes some of that information through jmx. I've been trying for about an hour now and I cant get jetty to start with jmx enabled. It doesn't help that 6.1.25 is so old that I can barely find any documentation.

Comment: We need to add `org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-management:6.1.25` in dependencies, does that mean the versions should be matched? I mean `jetty-management` and `jetty`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I would imagine if you went a few (minor) versions up or down, it would still work.

Comment: I'm curious now: Why do you need to know jetty version?

Comment: That's because I want to use webjar, which is supported directly by servlet 3.x containers. Which is not working well if I use gradle jetty plugin, so I want to know the jetty version to figure it out

Comment: You should really looking into Gretty